# Story about main character with regeneration powers

Tags: story-identification

I read a book 10+ years ago where the world was ruled by various factions, each one had a special ability of some sort.
The main characters faction had regenerative ability. Another faction had the ability to speed up or slow down time.
I am not sure of the plot, but I know at one point he is injured so badly he starts growing a clone which he attempts to kill, but comes back later in the story.

Any ideas?

Comment: See also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34609/book-about-outcasts-from-earth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[A Planet Called Treason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Planet_Called_Treason)* by Orson Scott Card. The main character is Lanik Mueller. All Muellers have regenerative abilities, but he is an outcast despite being a member of the royal family because his body is growing features he doesn't need, such as breasts and extra arms. The Ku Kuei are the ones who can modify the flow of time.

Comment: That was it definitely, thanks!