# SF novel with sentient planet that consumes the bad guys

Tags: story-identification, sentience

The book involved a group that had crashed onto a planet that
augmented their natural abilities. A group of characters (the bad guys)
became talented liars and politicians. A geologist (the good guy)
could communicate with the sentient planet. Eventually, he talked the
planet into swallowing the bad guys.

Comment: When did you read this book? What year? Can you recall any details about the cover (colours, people, etc).  Also, try this [list of sentient planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_living_planets) to see if anything stands out.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Orson Scott Card's novel [*A Planet Called Treason*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Planet_Called_Treason) (1979), later rewritten as *Treason* (1988).
In this book, different families have different territories and different talents, based on the occupations of their founders:

> Mueller―genetics. ...
>
> Schwartz, lost to all human contact on the desert―she had been a geologist.  Wasted on this world without hard metals. ...
>
> Anderson―the useless leader of the rebellion, whose only gift was politics.

The protagonist, Lanik Mueller, can regenerate his body parts; the Schwartzes can communicate with and control rocks and earth; and the Andersons can create illusions.
Collaborating with the Schwartzes, Lanik eventually manipulates the planet so that Anderson Island sinks into the ocean.

Comment: Good answer! If this does get accepted (sadly, rare on new Story ID questions), it's a Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32276/main-character-can-manipulate-his-own-time and a few others.